# Add memory to load_qa_chain in Streamlit app

Tags: python, streamlit, langchain, large-language-model

I'm facing several issues while trying to add memory to my streamlit application that is using gpt3.5 and load_qa_chain.
Following is the code where I instantiate the llm, vectordb, etc.

```
import os
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_text_splitters import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFium2Loader
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")



prompt_template = """xxxxxx


{context}

Question: {question}
Helpful Answer:"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"]
)



class PDFQuery:
    def __init__(self, openai_api_key = None) -> None:
        self.embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=openai_api_key)
        os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = openai_api_key
        self.text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=200, chunk_overlap=20)
        self.llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106", temperature=0, openai_api_key=openai_api_key)
        self.chain = None
        self.db = None

    def ask(self, question: str) -> str:
        if self.chain is None:
            response = "Base dati non popolata"
        else:
            docs = self.db.get_relevant_documents(question)
            response = self.chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=question)
        return response

    def ingest(self, file_path: os.PathLike) -> None:
        loader = PyPDFium2Loader(file_path)
        documents = loader.load()
        splitted_documents = self.text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
        self.db = Chroma.from_documents(splitted_documents, self.embeddings, persist_directory="./chroma_db").as_retriever()
        self.chain = load_qa_chain(self.llm, chain_type="stuff", prompt=PROMPT)

    def forget(self) -> None:
        self.db = None
        self.chain = None
```

Then, in another python script, I use the following function whenever the user inputs a query for the llm to answer:

```
def process_input():
    if st.session_state["user_input"] and len(st.session_state["user_input"].strip()) > 0:
        user_text = st.session_state["user_input"].strip()
        with st.session_state["thinking_spinner"], st.spinner(f"Calcolando..."):
            query_text = st.session_state["pdfquery"].ask(user_text)

        st.session_state["messages"].append((user_text, True))
        st.session_state["messages"].append((query_text, False))

        # Clear user input after processing
        st.session_state["user_input"] = ""
```

Can someone help in adding the memory to my chatbot? It already answers questions correctly but it is not able to remember previous conversations.

Tried following several guides regarding adding memory to streamlit chatbots, but found them very confusing and was always getting errors when implementing the suggested code.